# how to make pandas not read display values from csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

I have a date column in csv file like as shown below

```
23/6/2011 7:00     
21/4/1998 05:00       
17/02/1990  
11/01/1985 30:30:01       
26/02/1976 
45:42:7
```

But the problem here is, when I double click the `rows in csv, the actual date value is correctly displayed` 15/02/2010 10:30:00` etc.

My csv looks like as below

[image]

But I cannot do this manually because you can imagine, I have 20-30 csv files and there are lot of rows like this.

So, when I read the column in pandas dataframe and apply `datetime` function like below,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

> ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 55:45.0

But how can I make pandas read the actual value and not csv display value?

I tried changing the format in excel csv file but that doesn't help
Basically I want pandas to read the double clicked value from csv but not the display value?

Comment: When you open your csv in notepad or some other plain text editor what values are displayed?

Comment: "csv display value" - CSV is a text file. There is no display value. The display is only from whatever it is you are using (Excel?). Open a text editor and show us the actual contents of your file.

Comment: For future reference... CSV is *not* Excel, and Excel is mostly unhelpful when working with CSVs.

Comment: @All - I updated the question with screenshot

Comment: Please don't use Excel, instead use Notepad or some other plain text editor, as mentioned/stressed in previous comments.

Comment: So, YOu suggest me to read `pandas.read_txt`? instead of read.csv?

Comment: @TheGreat since `.csv` file is not an excel file, but a 'delimited text file that uses a comma to separate values', Excel is not only unnecessary to show what's in the file, but makes it harder to understand what is actually in the file (due to excel also doing some processing to display those values). That's why people were asking to see what the file looks like opened in a text editor (e.g. notepad) instead of Excel.

Comment: Open the CSV **in Notepad** and show us what the column looks like.